# How to set spinner title which is came from Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I have Navigation drawer which has category and subcategory. Clicking  on subcategory  related product display on recycler  view using fragment .  Above fragment  I have customise header same like toolbar which is having spinner. Till now I successfully  created all. But my question is.

1)  how to set spinner title which is not  selected from spinner.  Which is selected from navigation  drawer. 
Like : navigation drawer array having 
 Abc
 Pqr
 Xyz
While clicking on AbC  from navigation drawer. Abc  become title of spinner Nd pqr and xyz below it. Please  help.

2) spinner array having  same array  Abc,Pqr,Xyz . When user select ABC  or any  thing  from navigation  drawer that become title Nd other show below it.

I added some logic  like comparing spinner array to item which I  selected from navigation drawer  using if else all working fine while debug. But not showing  result properly

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do is `setSelection` of Spinner as per item selected in Navigation Drawer,

Solution is get position of item in array which is currently selected in `NavigationDrawer` and user spinners method to show current selection:-

Method is `spinner.setSelection(position)`

For example, say you've select `pqr` from `NavigationDrawer` then `spinner.setSelection(1)` can be used to select item in `spinner` as your `pqr` is at second number in you `array`

Comment: Plz send some code  so that  I can implement  it.  Thanks  for help.

Comment: Well, show me what you did so far? May be I can look up into your code.

Comment: //  dropdownSubcategoriesArray is drop down of spinner
            //selecteditem is my  navigation selection
            if (dropdownSubcategoriesArray.size() > 0) {
                dropdownSubcategoriesArray.add(0, selecteditem);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dropdownSubcategoriesArray);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

Comment: @Puja, this is not readable code :( Edit your question with your snippet

Comment: i did it myself . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it display navigation drawer selected item with other array which have five item . i want to remove which is matches to another array.

```
            if (dropdownSubcategoriesArray.size() > 0) {
                dropdownSubcategoriesArray.add(0, selecteditem);
            }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dropdownSubcategoriesArray);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

  }
}
```